# Formatting an NdefFormatable NFC tag with Javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native, format, nfc, ndef

I'm trying to format a NFC tag using javascript, from NdefFormatable to Ndef. All the sources I found were using the chariotsolution's java library, which is built on Cordova, so it's useless to my react-native javascript Android app.
(link: https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc)

Is there some general way to format NdefFormatable tags so I can use whitedogg13's react-native-nfc-manager library to start writing Ndef messages?
(link: https://github.com/whitedogg13/react-native-nfc-manager)

By some general way I mean is there a way I can implement it myself with javascript or even use a 3rd party app? I just want to get to writing messages to my tags without porting an entire java library, for which I am far too inexperienced.

Just to be clear I'm not looking for code snippets (although they are welcome), merely a way to format NdefFormatable NFC tags, so I can implement it myself, preferably trough javascript code.

The NFC tags im using are ISO 15693 standard. (Link: https://www.hidglobal.com/sites/default/files/resource_files/hid-rfid-il-frequency-hf-tags-ct-en.pdf)
"Embeddable RFID"

Thanks, let me know if I need to provide any more info.

Comment: Did you have any success with these tags? There seems to be a chip change in 2014 that some tablets and phones have difficulty reading/writing to.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are ok to use 3rd party app, I recommend using [NXP's NFC TagWriter App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter&hl=en) or the [NXP TagXplorer tool](https://www.nxp.com/products/rfid-nfc/nfc-hf/nfc-readers/tagxplorer-pc-based-nfc-tag-reader-writer-tool:TAGXPLORER)